# How to change the grouped TableViews selected background color

Tags: iphone, tableview

I am using a grouped table view for my iPhone application, for which I need to change the selected background color to red. I can set it, but the problem is that the first table cell the views are outside the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

try to this....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // clear the cell background color 

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

1)cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleRed;

OR

2)cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

```
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
```

use any of above code will solve your problem if still your problem is not solved put your code i'll try to solve